# How can we Verify Json response using Beanshell in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

> I am getting Json as a response.
>   Instead of using multiple jsonPath_assertion I want to check it in single beanshell.
>   Each time I am getting Response with different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use beanshell assertion.It will help you a lot.
>   `prev.getResponseDataAsString()` will return your json response as a string.
>   I hope you would be using Jsonpath online evaluator for evaluating json responses. 
>   Suppose if my json online evaluator code looks like this `$.items[2].CM_SEQNUMBER`
>   In beanshell assertion i have used

```
 JsonObject jsonobj = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString);
    JsonArray jsonarr = jsonobj.get("items").asArray();
    String pickupToCheck=jsonarr.get(2).asObject().get("CM_SEQNUMBER").asString();
```

> Similarly you can verify your JSON data without using multiple JSONPath Extractor using single beanshell assertion.

Comment: Thank you for your feedBack

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/) instead.

Groovy has built-in [JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/) so you will be able to use [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class to parse the response like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
// do what you need here
```

Besides Groovy performs much better than Beanshell and it is [recommended](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to use it for scripting in JMeter. See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more information.